# How to Iterate through a select option list using a class Id

Tags: jquery

[image]
As you can see, I have a td with a className templateCell . I need to iterate through the td and find the option having text as (inactive) and mark its attribute as disabled to true.
This is what Expect. Please click the link.
http://jsfiddle.net/atqLwm5u/4/

Anything marked as (inactive). I want to disable that item from my mulitiselect dropdownlist .

This is what i have tried. This is what i get. It does not change anything in my selected item.
ANY idea How to Prevent Default after a tag call ??
[image]

This is what i have thought

```
<select id="dp1" class="text_select" name="field_0_1" >
<option value="Version0" > Version0 </option>
<option value="Version1(inactive)"> Version1(inactive) </option>
<option value="Version2(inactive)">Version2(inactive) </option>
<option value="Version3">PVersion3 </option>  
</select>
//Jquery 
$(".text_select option[value*='inactive']").attr('disabled','true');
```

I think i need to iterate and use this above example.
What you are seeing is a Kendo UI multiselect Select2 dropdownlist HTML tags.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I am confused - your jsfiddle works ?

Comment: When i try it with the above tag and in the application it does not work . I am confused also. I feel like i need to iterate it. Please look at the html screenshot.

Comment: How can i prevent default any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

Given you just want to look at the innerText of the options, you can use the following:

`$('.templateCell select option:contains("inactive")').attr('disabled','true');`

This will select all `option` elements that contain the text "inactive" that are within the `select` that's located in the `td.templateCell` element and set the disabled property to true, given that the option innerText contains "inactive".

Comment: I tried this alex, i have added the screenshot of my console.

Comment: How can i prevent default any idea ?